# Checking and preventing similar strings while insertion in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, hash, combinations, similarity

## Brief info

I have 3 tables:

**Set:**

```
id
name
```

**SetItem:**

```
set_id
item_id
position
```

**TempSet:**

```
id
```

I have a function that generates new random combinations from `Item` table. Basically, always after successful generation, I create a new row in `Set` table, get it's id and add all item ids into `SetItem` table.

## Problem

Every time before generating new combination I truncate the `TempSet` table, fill new item ids into this table and check for similarity percentage by comparing with previous combinations in `SetItem` table. if new combination similarity greater or equal to 30%, I need to prevent this combination and re-generate new combination.

Similarity means - existence of elements on previously generated combinations. So, the idea is:

if more than 3 element of newly generated set repeated on some previously generated set, prevent it and try to generate another combination.

Here is function that generates new combinations:

```
  CREATE DEFINER = `root` @`localhost` FUNCTION `gen_uniq_perm_by_kw` (
    comboSize INT ( 5 ),
    tries INT ( 3 ) 
    ) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8 SQL SECURITY INVOKER BEGIN
    iterat :
    LOOP
        DELETE 
        FROM
            `TempSet`;
        INSERT INTO `TempSet` ( `id` ) (
            SELECT
                `i`.`id` 
            FROM
                `Item` AS `i`
            ORDER BY
                RAND( ) 
                LIMIT comboSize 
            );
        IF
            (
            SELECT
                1 
            FROM
                `SetItem` 
            GROUP BY
                `set_id` 
            HAVING
                sum(
                CASE
                        
                        WHEN EXISTS (
                        SELECT
                            id 
                        FROM
                            `TempSet` 
                        WHERE
                            `id` = `item_id` 
                            LIMIT 1 
                            ) THEN
                            1 ELSE 0 
                        END 
                        ) / count( 1 ) * 100 >= 30 
                        LIMIT 1 
                        ) < 1 THEN
                        RETURN ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( id SEPARATOR '-' ) FROM `TempSet` );
                    
                END IF;
                
                SET tries := tries - 1;
                IF
                    tries = 0 THEN
                        RETURN NULL;
                    
                END IF;
                
            END LOOP iterat;
        
END
```

When I test it, even when newly generated combination's elements doesn't exist in any other previously generated combination, it returns null as a result.

My question is, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Fix your data structure so you have the items stored one per row rather than in a string.  That is the right way to store data in SQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I already have it. How can it help me?

Comment: I have separate table, where combination elements stored in many-to-many relationship structure

Comment: Delete this question and ask another question, describing that data structure.

Comment: for this case is better to use graph database that can show in how many combinations concrette element exist. check `neo4j`. otherwise develop 2 worksers: `generator` and `validator`. `Generator` will generate combination string and will set `isValid: 0`, `isValidated: 0` flags. `Validator` will work on `isValidated: 0` records and will check every element of every row and validate for Your conditions and set `isValid: 1` if it's ok and `isValidated: 1` to prevent validating it again.

Comment: `comboSize INT ( 5 )` does not initialize `comboSize` to `5`.

Comment: How many sets will there be?  A thousand?  A million?

Comment: What is the purpose of `position`?

Comment: @RickJames half a million at least and it's growing

Comment: @RickJames position of element in combination. It matters

Comment: The edited question has nothing to do with the orginal post dated July 12 2017. so my answer looks outdated. In such case, ask a new question, this thread is now impossible to follow

Answer (score 2):

*My question is, what am I doing wrong?*

You don't have any data in your SetItem table.

Edit: You commented that this is wrong; you do have 300k rows in SetItem.

---

I got an example working. It appears that you can't use a scalar subquery like you're doing. I got it working this way:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS gen_uniq_perm_by_kw;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER = `root` @`localhost` FUNCTION `gen_uniq_perm_by_kw` (comboSize INT, tries INT) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8 SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
        iterat :
        LOOP
                DELETE FROM `TempSet`;

                INSERT INTO `TempSet` (`id`)
                SELECT `i`.`id` FROM `Item` AS `i` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT comboSize;

                IF EXISTS(
                        SELECT set_id,
                                SUM(CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT id FROM `TempSet` WHERE `id` = `item_id` LIMIT 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS group_sum,
                                COUNT(*) AS group_count
                        FROM `SetItem`
                        GROUP BY `set_id`
                        HAVING group_sum * 10 / group_count < 3
                ) THEN
                        RETURN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR '-') FROM `TempSet`);
                END IF;

                SET tries = tries - 1;

                IF tries = 0 THEN
                        RETURN NULL;
                END IF;
        END LOOP iterat;
END
```

I also got it working in a simpler way, without using the SUM and extra subquery:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS gen_uniq_perm_by_kw;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER = `root` @`localhost` FUNCTION `gen_uniq_perm_by_kw` (comboSize INT, tries INT) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8 SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
        iterat :
        LOOP
                DELETE FROM `TempSet`;

                INSERT INTO `TempSet` (`id`)
                SELECT `i`.`id` FROM `Item` AS `i` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT comboSize;

                IF EXISTS(
                        SELECT s.set_id,
                                COUNT(t.id) AS group_matches,
                                COUNT(*) AS group_count
                        FROM SetItem AS s LEFT OUTER JOIN TempSet AS t ON t.id = s.item_id
                        GROUP BY s.set_id
                        HAVING group_matches * 10 / group_count < 3
                ) THEN
                        RETURN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR '-') FROM `TempSet`);
                END IF;

                SET tries = tries - 1;

                IF tries = 0 THEN
                        RETURN NULL;
                END IF;
        END LOOP iterat;
END
```

Comment: `You don't have any data in your SetItem table.`:  I have set id <-> item id, relation based data there. Around 300k rows from previous combinations. for example, if item ids: 123, 124, 320 are in set id 1 then SetItem looks like, `1 | 123 | 1; 1 | 124 | 2; 1 | 320 | 3`

Comment: Here are the results: `["11820","5548","5019","6247","8254","9469","5512","3482","7304","10011","6170","12514","5039","14429","5573","9453"]

["6247","8254","11820","9452","12220","4212","6170","14429","5548","5512","10088","12514","8960","5019","5573","9489"]` I manually counted repeating elements. There are more than 3 repeating elements in these sets

Comment: I copied your `>= 3` condition from your original attempt. But it seems you need the opposite condition `< 3` if you want only those that *don't* have 30% match. I have edited my answer above.

Comment: The result must be <=3 matches or no match at all

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to join a chatroom. Please edit your question and provide an example of data and the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to get a bit loosey-goosey with the "same", consider this alternative:

- Instead of hashes written as numbers, consider the hast to be a bit position in a bit string.
- BIT_COUNT(a.bits & b.bits) gives the number of bits that are the same in both bitstrings.

In older versions of MySQL, you are limited to 64-bit `BIGINT UNSIGNED` strings unless you are willing to have a bunch of them and add up the counts.  (I've written code for such.)  With newer versions, `BLOB` can be used with this operation.

Regardless of the hashing (numbers, 0..63, blob), there is a chance of collisions.  In many applications, this can be ignored as a minor 'noise' in the system.  What is your situation?

What I propose is a lot faster and possibly smaller (data-wise) than the design you outlined.

Comment: First I would like to better understand the ultimate goal.  And where numbers like 10885 come from.  (That is rather small and duplication-prone for a hash.)

Comment: The number are coming from items.  Item table has auto-incremented id.

Comment: Then a 20K bitstring would work, without any loosey-goosey.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with MySQL 5.7 and JSON functions enabled, you can do this:

```
set @v1 = CONCAT("[", (SELECT group_concat(r.id SEPARATOR ',') FROM (select o.id from test.item o order by rand() limit 10) r), "]");
```

Now @v1 has a JSON_ARRAY of 10 random item elements.

With this query you will know item collection collission:

```
select set_id, @v1 as serie, count(*) * 10 as CollisionPercentage from test.setitem 
where JSON_CONTAINS(@v1, JSON_ARRAY(item_id))
group by set_id, serie
order by CollisionPercentage desc;
```

First CollisionPercentage value determine maximum collision.

**EDITED**

Try with this. Pay attention with declared database names.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS gen_uniq_perm_by_kw;
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE DEFINER = `root` @`localhost` FUNCTION `gen_uniq_perm_by_kw` (comboSize INT, tries INT, collisions INT) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8 SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
        iterat :
        LOOP
                set @v1 = CONCAT(
                    '[', 
                    (SELECT group_concat(r.id SEPARATOR ',') FROM (select o.id from test.item o order by rand() limit comboSize) r), 
                    ']'
                );


                IF EXISTS(
                select set_id, count(*) * 10 as CollisionPercentage from test.setitem 
                    where JSON_CONTAINS(@v1, JSON_ARRAY(item_id))
                    group by set_id
                    having count(*) < collisions
                    order by CollisionPercentage desc
                    LIMIT 1
                ) THEN
                        RETURN @v1;
                END IF;

                SET tries = tries - 1;

                IF tries = 0 THEN
                        RETURN NULL;
                END IF;
        END LOOP iterat;
END;;


DELIMITER ;

select gen_uniq_perm_by_kw(5,5,30);
```

With result

```
+--------------------------------------+
| test.gen_uniq_perm_by_kw(5,5,30) |
+--------------------------------------+
| [30111,10916,13446,6617,10918]       |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm very busy. I thought that show the way was enough.

Comment: @TuralAliyev check if wors for you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking against the MD5 checksum you should check for your 10 fresh generated item_id's wether there are 3 or more occurrences within one set-id.

You must not check:

```
SELECT  count( * ) 
FROM    `Set` 
WHERE   `Set`.`hash` = @md5 
LIMIT 1
```

But instead of that you should check:

```
select  1
from    setitems
where   item_id in ( a,b,c, put here your 10 fresh generated item )
group by set_id
having  count(1) >= 3
limit   1
```

This query will return a 1 when there exists a set with 3 or more item_id's in your "in-list".

When the number of items varies (not always 10) then you could also count the items in a group to calculate the percentage:

```
select  1
from    setitems
group by set_id
having  sum( 
          case when find_in_set(item_id , @list)
          then 1
          else 0
          end
        ) / count(1) * 100 >= 30
limit 1;
```

@list should be comma-separated
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Comment: there might be more than 10 items, is it okay?

Comment: That is possible, but you should decide how the percentage is calculated.... I my example i used >= 3 That corresponds to 30% of the existing set.... When this is the formula you should also determine the count of items in a set to find the percentage...

Comment: I can't help you with that, i don't write mysql code.

Comment: This line: `CASE WHEN `item_id` IN @list THEN` gives me error.  `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ...`

Comment: try this:

case when find_in_set( item_id , @list )
          then 1
          else 0
          end

for this function your list should be comma seperated.... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152843/discussion-between-hetorakel-and-tural-aliyev).

Comment: @llaroot - "hard time to implement your solution on existing function" -- You need to abandon your function; hetOrakel's is much simpler.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE `combinations` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `nb` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `orderid` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `orderid`),
    INDEX `On_nb` ( `nb`,`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_bin'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;


insert into `combinations` values
(1, 13446,1),
(1, 10860,2),
(1, 10885,3),
(1, 10853,4),
(1, 13048,5),
(1, 13044,6),
(1, 10918,7),
(1, 10916,8),
(1, 6519,9),
(1, 10860,10),
(2, 13527,1),
(2, 10933,2),
(2, 10928,3),
(2, 10922,4),
(2, 6595,5),
(2, 10944,6),
(2, 13446,7),
(2, 10860,8),
(2, 10885,9),
(2, 19888,10),
(3, 13364,1),
(3, 12949,2),
(3, 6732,3),
(3, 6763,4),
(3, 13542,5),
(3, 6617,6),
(3, 13125,7),
(3, 13058,8),
(3, 13059,9),
(3, 30111,10);


select c1.id, count(c1.nb) from `combinations`as c1, `combinations` as c_ori
where c1.nb=c_ori.nb and c_ori.id=2 and  c1.id!=c_ori.id
group by c1.id having count(c1.nb)>=3

"id"    "count(c1.nb)"
"1" "4"
```

As this last query returns something, 2nd combinations already exists with a granularity of at least 30%.
Please note that in your first combinations, number 10860 is there twice. This algorithm doesn't take into account properly duplicated numbers. Do you require duplicated numbers in your combinations ?

Comment: it was mistake. 1 number can be only 1 time in combination

Comment: I need more explanation

Comment: So if all combinations have 10 numbers, query like "select c1.id, count(c1.nb) from `combinations`as c1, `combinations` as c_ori
where c1.nb=c_ori.nb and c_ori.id=9999 and  c1.id!=c_ori.id
group by c1.id having count(c1.nb)>=3;" where 9999 is the last inserted combination id checks that there is similar data in table : it will return rows if there are such combinations and nothing if there is no similar combinations.

Comment: you could put combination to test before insert in another table (called for example temp_combination) with same structure. query to test new combination would be then "select c1.id, count(c1.nb) from combinations as c1, temp_combinations as c_ori where c1.nb=c_ori.nb and c_ori.id=9999 and c1.id!=c_ori.id group by c1.id having count(c1.nb)>=3;" if no row is returned, you could move content from temp_combinations to `combinations`

Comment: This query compute the quantity of matching numbers per combination. the statement "having count(c1.nb)" makes sure that only the combinations with at least 3 matching numbers will be returned

Comment: The edited question has nothing to do with the orginal post. so my answer looks outdated. In such case, ask a new question, this thread is now impossible to follow.

Comment: This is a difficult situation, but deleting the question is impossible, rolling it back would invalidate the other answers and yours was not particularly successful prior to the revision. For this answer, I suggest either deleting it or copying a quote from the first version of the question so that it is clear what you are answering. You might also answer the question in the revised state with this answer or in another answer. But at this point I'd probably just delete and walk away from this one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, data structure in new question is not adapted at all to such search as there are to search amongst 300 000 combinations, the data structure I show above can be used to develop a function to generate new keys but it won't be based on existing gen_uniq_perm_by_kw function framework (which doesn't work anyway).