# Assigning query's results into variable inside MySQL procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, stored-procedures

Here is the piece of sql from my procedure:

```
   .... 
   SET @list := (
        SELECT
            `i`.`id` 
        FROM
            `Item` AS `i`
        Order by RAND()
        LIMIT 10
        );
    RETURN CONCAT_WS( '-', @list );
```

Inside procedure, I need to set query's results (yes, query returns multiple rows as a result) into some variable.

Then as a second variable, I need to concatenate previous results into one string.

But when I do it, I get following error:

`Sub-query returns more than 1 row`

So the question is, what am I doing wrong?

By the way, I know about `group_concat`. In second part of procedure, there is a requirement for checking if some id exists on this `@list` variable: `find_in_set(`item_id`, @list )` 
And the query returns random results every time when I call it. 
That's why, calling sub-query 2 times: 1 time as group concat string, second time just as list of results is not a solution for me. So, I need them as a set stored in variable.

Answer (score 1):

You are approaching this is exactly the wrong way.  There is no reason to store the ids in a list.

In the second part of the procedure, you should just be using a subquery:

```
where exists (select 1
              from item i
              where i.id = <outer table>.item_id
             )
```

If you really did want to put things into a list, you would use `group_concat()` as you allude to:

```
    SELECT @list := GROUP_CONCAT(i.id  ORDER BY RAND() SEPARATOR '-') as ids
    FROM Item i;
```

I don't see a use for storing the value in a variable, nor for ordering the ids randomly.

Comment: Sir, look, this procedure generates random combinations. And after generation I'm checking if this combination's ids exists on previously generated combinations or not, so I need the same combination for generating concatenation and check. You suggest to call that query multiple times, if I get you right. But it's not solution for my case

Comment: For making things clear, I'm pasting full procedure's sql: https://pastebin.com/dj4RNXkX

Comment: The root of the problem is here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45057324/971388 I'm working on this aproach because of one of answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45878858/971388

Answer (score 0):

*So the question is, what am I doing wrong?*

What you're doing wrong is trying to store a result set in a user variable.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html says:

> User variables can be assigned a value from a limited set of data types: integer, decimal, floating-point, binary or nonbinary string, or NULL value.

This kind of variable cannot store an array or a result set. Only one scalar value.

This question has code that seems to be related to [Checking and preventing similar strings while insertion in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45057324/checking-and-preventing-similar-strings-while-insertion-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You should try following solution to overcome the issue of storing large data, it might help others too looking for solution:

```
# sets the default 1Mb storage limit to 10Mb
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = (1024*10);

SET @list :=  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM `Item` AS `i` Order by RAND() LIMIT 10);
```